# How can I extract data from a list of parent objects with children?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a list inside a class inside of a list where the classes are defined like so:

```
class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Class2> Class2s { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I can create a list of a class of type `Result` where `Result` is:

```
class Result
{
    public int Class1Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the `Result` class contains values from `Class1` and `Class2`.

Like so:

```
var results = new List<Result>();
foreach (var class1 in class1s) //class1s is a List of Class1
{
    foreach (var class2 in class1.Class2s)
    {
        results.Add(new Result()
        {
            Class1Id = class1.Id,
            Name = class2.Name,
            Value = class2.Value,
        };
    }
}
```

How can I do this via a linq query?

I have tried the following:

```
IList<Result> list = class1s.Select(c => c.Class2s.Select(c2 => new Result()
{
    Class1Id = c.Id,
    Type = c2.Type,
    Name = c2.Name,
}).ToList()).ToList();
```

But this fails with the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<Results>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Results>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

**NOTE:**

The duplicates do not answer the question as they do not address the issue when the resultant list is a list of the inner classes AND using a property of the inner class.

Comment: @CodeCaster and how am I supposed to do that with SelectMany when one of the properties is in the outer class not the list?

Comment: I suggest you edit the title and question to explain that you want to include data from the parent objects. As it is, the immediate answer to "How to flatten a list of lists" is "Use SelectMany". The one important difference is lost in the code

Comment: You don't have a list of lists either, you have a list of parent and child objects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is the edit any better? I'm having trouble coming up with a title so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Retrieving data from a list of parents and children can be done easily in query format by using two `from` statements

```
var results = from parent in class1s
              from child in parent.Class2s 
              select new Result {
                    Class1Id = parent.Id,
                    Name = child.Name,
                    Value = child.Value,
              };
var list=results.ToList();
```

In the fluent format, you can use SelectMany

```
var list = class1s.SelectMany(parent => parent.Class2s,
                              (parent,child)=>
                                           new Result {
                                              Class1Id = parent.Id,
                                              Name = child.Name,
                                              Value = child.Value
                                          }
           ).ToList();
```

I prefer the first form for obvious reasons

Notice that I use the [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts a result selector. Without it I'd have to use a `Select` inside the first selector function, resulting in even more cumbersome code

Comment: Can it be done easily in the other format (can't remember its name)?

Comment: Not *that* easy, which is why I'm trying it first. Besides, they are equivalent

Comment: I know they are equivalent I just personally prefer the other format but thanks for your help

Comment: @TheLethalCoder in this case you'll agree it's not the most elegant form

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in non-query format using the following:

```
results = class1s.SelectMany(c => c.Class2s.Select(c2 => new Result()
        {
            Class1Id = c.Id,
            Name = c2.Name,
            Value = c2.Value,
        })).ToList();
```

Note that it's very similar to your original attempt but using `SelectMany` on the `class1s` rather than `Select`.

Comment: No need for the double select, `SelectMany` has an override that accepts a  result selector.

Comment: That's a good point @PanagiotisKanavos. I'll leave this here as an alternative approach but upvote your answer as it's way more comprehensive.

Comment: I started writing *this* version too, but then remembered that sometimes there are unexpected overloads that make things a lot simpler

Comment: I was too tied in to the OPs original code - that'll teach me to rush an answer :)